# PSql: how to not remove comments for external editor?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I like to use `psql`, and sometimes I commenting part of query (usually one line) - something like "quick fix and see what you get".

Internal `psql` editor is not suitable for big queries, and so often I'm using external editor via `\e` (currently it's `vim`).

The problem is when some part of query is currently commented in `psql`, then it appearing as empty line in external editor.

How I can configure `psql` to not remove comments when external editor is called?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but speaking personally I prefer to work in a .sql files and then use `\i`, so as to avoid typing queries directly in psql. That way, you can write as many comments as you want and have the queries in directly usable format if you need them again later.

Comment: I wrote a [blog article](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/02/21/more-out-of-psql/) on how to use a Vim server mode from within psql. This way you can keep your queries safe outside psql.

Comment: I would love for this to be configurable, I often use an external editor while prototyping queries - but having comments stripped each time makes it a pain to selectively exclude/include variations at will.

Comment: plus 1 for indirectly teaching me `\e` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always used `/* COMMENT */` for temporarily commenting part of code, because I thought it would loose the rest on a query (after `--`) cos it [converts code to one line](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

> The new query buffer is then re-parsed according to the normal rules
>   of psql, where the whole buffer is treated as a single line

(((I had same bug in Oracle 8.smth something - dumping package it was ignoring all characters after `--` comment in package code)))

Surprisingly `\e` editor loses only one line (the commented with `--` one).

**Answer**: use `/**/` commenting and it will keep comment through runs

**Hint**: if you use `vim` you can jump to the end of line by `ESC + $` sequence, so it is not big difference in efforts from `--` commenting